# Почему await не работает в ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

```
async def check():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        executor.submit(run_payment_in_thread, session_str, api_id, api_hash, sess_name, bot_url, check, msg,
                        callback_data, currency_iso,
                        curs_rub, state)
```

```
def run_payment_in_thread(session_str, api_id, api_hash, sess_name, bot_url, check, msg, callback_data, currency_iso,
                          curs_rub, state):
    asyncio.run(
        check_payment(session_str, api_id, api_hash, sess_name, bot_url, check, msg, callback_data, currency_iso,
                      curs_rub, state))
```

```
async def check_payment(session_str, api_id, api_hash, sess_name, bot_url, check, msg, callback_data, currency_iso,
                        curs_rub, state):
    start_time = time.time()
    client = Client(session_name=session_str,
                    api_id=api_id,
                    api_hash=api_hash,
                    app_version="8.2",
                    system_version="macOS 15.0",
                    device_model='MacBook Pro 14" M1 Pro'
                    )

    await client.start()
    logger.debug(f"--- {time.time() - start_time} seconds |запус |---")
```

Это все я запускаю внутри бота aiogram, дальше `await client.start()` не идет, почему?

Comment: Проблема не в executor. Не идет дальше потому, что `start`, очевидно, не заканчивается. Этот код сам по себе рабочий (в том, что касается запуска потока и корутин, посмотрите https://paste.in/w96vbx), хотя и не ясно зачем вам тут отдельный поток, если внутри все равно асинхронный код, лучше так https://paste.in/YaTriv

Comment: мне так надо, без ThreadPoolExecutor await client.start() работает, а с ним нет

Comment: нет смысла в тред пуле. а пул процессов даст возможность запускать новый луп